# Query a record without knowing which table it resides in

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have around 100+ tables, all of them have a column ID (Primary key).

My task is, when a user enter an ID number, I need to find the table that record belongs to, then retrieve all the data from that table.

I thought of the following options but they are not working, because:

1. UNION: Too many tables, each table has different columns.
2. VIEW: Data in each table are updated very frequently.

What are the other options?

p/s: Due to the requirement, I have to avoid using T-SQL.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to have a singular unique ID across 100+ tables that you could enter in an ID and have it match just one table... Are you staggering your identity seeds?  Or are you actually wanting to pull back every table that has a record with ID N?

Comment: Surely, the output/result will need to be consistent, i.e. if you union (and rename/recast), you will still need to be getting "similar fields" from each.  You could also use a View to consolidate and then just query that, but I would not condone any of that - but it is a solution.

Comment: I have tables like `Table_Apple, Table_Orange, Table_Lemon` etc. etc. SO each table will still have `ID`, but different fruits will have different features/description. So, when I was given an ID, first I need to find out which `fruit` that ID belongs to, then all the data related to that specific `record`

Comment: Additionally, this is a legacy database, so there aren't much (good) data integrity.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like bad database design, but you could do this:

Build a new table that stores the ID number and the table the item resides in.

Populate this table with a stored procedure that runs occasionally (depending on how often you get new records).  You could also just run this stored procedure whenever you add a record.

Now you can query one table to figure out where you need to query and use a second query to get the correct data.  Not ideal, but faster, I think, than other options.

Comment: I agree with you. Usually in cases like this, there should be a table with just (i.e. ID and Fruit Name - PK and FK relationship)

Comment: You should see the database I have to work with every day, big noxious ugly thing, and we aren't allowed to change any existing architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you specifically say you can't use T-SQL. However, for reference purposes, and for those who do not have the same limitation:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ID = [x]"
```

This will exectute a query on all tables in the database, where ? is a placeholder for tablename. 
Note, however, this is an undocumented SP, and may be let go in future releases.

Comment: I disagree with the downvote. This is still an answer to the question, only with one limitation removed. For others searching SO this could still be valuable information (I hope) if they are allowed to use the SP. (I'm not sure if I'd actually advocate it, since its unsupported, but it is nice and compact.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  The @MagicNumber is the ID value you are looking for.  This SQL also takes into account tables that do NOT have the ID column.

Did you mean you do not want a SQL answer?  Because your attempts seemed to imply the opposite, (UNION, VIEW).  Even if you do not want a T-SQL answer, and are looking to use something like SSIS, you still will need to write T-SQL to solve it.  This is why I have posted your solution using T-SQL.

If this does not solve your problem, please expand what you are looking for when you say, 
"p/s: Due to the requirement, I have to avoid using T-SQL." (sic.)

```
declare @MagicNumber int; set @MagicNumber=10
declare @st varchar(max)


DECLARE @name varchar(1000)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 

select st.name
from sys.tables ST
join sys.columns SC on sc.object_id = st.object_id
where sc.name = 'ID'

OPEN db_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
set @st='
if exists (select 1 from '+@name+' where ID='+cast(@MagicNumber as varchar(100))+')
begin
select '''+@name+''' as [Table Name]
select * from '+@name+'
end
'
-- select @name, @st
exec (@st)

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Name
END 

CLOSE db_cursor 
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```